# Перекодировка в Javascript

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, а как можно числовое значение символа таблицы CP-1251 преобразовать в символ? Например, 224 в букву "а"?

Comment: Уважение О_о

Comment: мб alert(String.fromCharCode(224))?

Comment: @Dobby007, нет. UTF-16.

Comment: это пробовала использовать, символы получаются неведомые, не буква "а", а символ с черточкой наверху, вместо "б" с двумя черточками

Comment: какие еще варианты??? пишите

Comment: Вариант крайне прост и тривиален - lookup table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо просто сдвинуть таблицу unicode на соответствующую страницу. Определяется эмпирически.

```
function ord_1251(ch) {
  var num = ch.charCodeAt(0)-0x350;
  return num;
}

function chr_1251(num) {
  var ch = String.fromCharCode(num + 0x350);
  return ch;
}
```

Comment: попробую, спасибо

Comment: все четко работает),